# mpi4py with OpenMPI: "ValueError: message: cannot guess count, datatype extent 0 (lb:0, ub:0)" in message_simple

Tags: python, error-handling, openmpi

I have mpi4py 1.3 installed with openMPI 1.6. Simple mpi4py demos like helloworld.py are working. In my code I call `MPI.Comm.Allreduce(MPI.IN_PLACE, obj)` , where obj is a numpy array.
This results in the error message:

> ValueError: message: cannot guess count, datatype extent 0 (lb:0, ub:0)" in message_simple

Any clues on what I've done wrong?

Full traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ptycho_508.py", line 124, in <module>
   p = ptycho.ptycho_DM(p, numit=numit_DM, subpix=False)
  File "/afs/psi.ch/project/cxs/users/braun_p/epd/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ptycho/core_object_modes.py", line 1357, in ptycho_DM comm.Allreduce(MPI.IN_PLACE, obj)
  File "Comm.pyx", line 544, in mpi4py.MPI.Comm.Allreduce (src/mpi4py.MPI.c:63736)
  File "message.pxi", line 579, in mpi4py.MPI._p_msg_cco.for_allreduce (src/mpi4py.MPI.c:23465)
  File "message.pxi", line 532, in mpi4py.MPI._p_msg_cco.for_cro_recv (src/mpi4py.MPI.c:23068)
  File "message.pxi", line 144, in mpi4py.MPI.message_simple (src/mpi4py.MPI.c:19614)
ValueError: message: cannot guess count, datatype extent 0 (lb:0, ub:0)
message_simple in <http://mpi4py.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/src/MPI/message.pxi> is failing
```

Comment: Did you actually mean that you are calling `MPI.Comm.Allreduce(MPI.IN_PLACE, obj)` as in the traceback, because there is no such thing as `MPI.ALL` in the mpi4py API reference.

Comment: What is the value of `obj` in the call?